# Creating a configurable Wrapper

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 service references in my project to a 3rd party API. The first service is to their sandbox (test) environment, the second service is to their live environment.

I am writing a wrapper (C# .net 4.51) for these 2 services so that I don't have 2 exposes the services to other parts of my project and also so that if I ever want to swap out the API for another its a seamless integration into my existing project structure.

My question is, what is the best way or some ways to set the configuration so that the wrapper knows to the use the sandbox or live environments?

I was thinking there could be some type of constructor that took a setting parameter pointing to sandbox or test. But I wanted some other ideas, to see what other people have done.

Comment: Why not use your `app.config` or `web.config`? That's what they're there for.

Comment: I am using them.    I guess my question isn't being asked correctly.   I want to programmically change whether I hit sandbox or live from outside the wrapper itself

Comment: The app.config does have all settings for accessing the correct api

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking. You should look into creating interfaces above your wrapper, and then using something like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx), [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/), or [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). Basically you'll end up with a line of code like `IServiceWrapper myWrapper = dependencyInjector.GetComponent<IServiceWrapper>("Sandbox");` or `"Live"` or whatever. These libraries support creating and loading "components" by name, which is what you're after.

Comment: ok seems like im going down the right path i have the Interfaces already setup.  Thanks i will look into those injection options